# Migrating the asp.net core 3.1 to .net 6 error

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I am migrating one of the projects from .net core 3.1 to .net 6. One of the project is not building and throwing this error.

> ConfigureServicesExtensions.cs(62, 22): [CS1061] 'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Decorate' and no accessible extension method 'Decorate' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Please see the code example below where its failing after upgradte from .net 3.1 to 6.0

```
private static void RegisterCommandHandlers(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        //Scruptor package : https://andrewlock.net/using-scrutor-to-automatically-register-your-services-with-the-asp-net-core-di-container/
        serviceCollection.Scan(scan => scan.FromAssemblyOf<ICommand>()
            .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo(typeof(ICommandHandler<>))
                .Where(_ => !_.IsGenericType))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .WithTransientLifetime());
        serviceCollection.Decorate(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), typeof(CommandHandlerLoggingDecorator<>));
    }
```

Comment: its the newget package Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection is causing the failures to build the project .

Comment: Decorate and Scan methods are failing because they are no longer available in .net 6

Comment: They never were. They come from separate library.

Answer (score 0):

**If your packages are up to date** then, you can try this :

1. Clean and rebuild your Solution.
2. Restart VS

Comment: tried this so many times .

Comment: Could you provide us the Code that cause the issue please ?

Comment: looks like .net 6 has no IServiceCollection Decorate method thats why build is failing . is there alternative way to resolve this in .net 6

Answer (score 0):

More a guess than an answer - AFAIK build DI had never exposed any `Decorate` method, the one I know comes from [`Scrutor`](https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor) library. Check if this library is installed.

**UPD**

Based on the added code - just install the [`Scrutor` nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Scrutor).